# Как реализовать спрайты не через свойство background?

Tags: html, css, спрайт

Никак не могу совладать с одним из элементов при вёрстке.
Прошу, собственно, Вашей помощи.

**Вопрос:**
Как реализовать спрайты внутри подобного блока?

**Должно быть вот так (в состоянии покоя):**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Это состояние hover**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал через абсолютное позиционирование элемента с иконкой, но размер у каждой из иконок разные (одна из проблем). Кроме этого, хотелось бы имет возможность управлять иконками на стороне CMS, т.е. обойтись без "background".

**Сейчас я "добился" вот этого (спокойное состояние):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Hover:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, разметка не позволяет мне показывать только часть иконки. Идей пока нету, надеюсь, Вы подскажете, как можно решить эту проблему.

```css
.pageservices {
  padding: 4rem 0;
  background: #3d3d3d;
}

.pageservices h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.pageservices h3::after {
  content: '';
  width: 150px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #7cd3ac;
  display: block;
  margin: .6rem auto 4rem auto;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item .pageservices__inner {
  background-position: right bottom;
  min-height: 168px;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item .pageservices__inner .pageservices__title {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item .pageservices__inner .pageservices__title a {
  color: #000;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item .pageservices__inner .pageservices__title a:hover {
  color: #7cd3ac;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item .pageservices__inner .pageservices__title .fas {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item .pageservices__inner .pageservices__info {
  text-align: justify;
  color: #000;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item:hover {
  background-color: #7cd3ac;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item:hover .pageservices__inner .pageservices__title a {
  color: #fff;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item:hover .pageservices__inner .pageservices__title a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.pageservices .pageservices__item:hover .pageservices__inner .pageservices__info {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container-fluid pageservices">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Услуги</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="pageservices__item">
          <div class="pageservices__inner" style="background-image: url('http://nova.expnk.ru/pageservices-icons1.png');">
            <div class="pageservices__title">
              <a href="#">Тестовый заголовок</a><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="pageservices__info">
              <p>Nobis reprehenderit optio et eligendi numquam?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="pageservices__item">
          <div class="pageservices__inner" style="background-image: url('http://nova.expnk.ru/pageservices-icons1.png');">
            <div class="pageservices__title">
              <a href="#">Тестовый заголовок</a><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="pageservices__info">
              <p>Nobis reprehenderit optio et eligendi numquam?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="pageservices__item">
          <div class="pageservices__inner" style="background-image: url('http://nova.expnk.ru/pageservices-icons1.png');">
            <div class="pageservices__title">
              <a href="#">Тестовый заголовок</a><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="pageservices__info">
              <p>Nobis reprehenderit optio et eligendi numquam?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="pageservices__item">
          <div class="pageservices__inner" style="background-image: url('http://nova.expnk.ru/pageservices-icons1.png');">
            <div class="pageservices__title">
              <a href="#">Тестовый заголовок</a><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="pageservices__info">
              <p>Nobis reprehenderit optio et eligendi numquam?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="pageservices__item">
          <div class="pageservices__inner" style="background-image: url(http://nova.expnk.ru/pageservices-icons1.png);">
            <div class="pageservices__title">
              <a href="#">Тестовый заголовок</a><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="pageservices__info">
              <p>Nobis reprehenderit optio et eligendi numquam?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="pageservices__item">
          <div class="pageservices__inner" style="background-image: url(http://nova.expnk.ru/pageservices-icons1.png);">
            <div class="pageservices__title">
              <a href="#">Тестовый заголовок</a><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="pageservices__info">
              <p>Nobis reprehenderit optio et eligendi numquam?</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Честно, не пойму, почему не подгружается картинка по абсолютному пути.** Надеюсь, такого кода будет достаточно. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А почему не использовать относительные пути?

Comment: @MaximLensky на локалке у меня относительные пути, я хотел чтобы Вы смогли увидеть эти "спрайты", поэтому прописал абсолютные пути, но безуспешно)))

Comment: вы пишите эти относительные пути в таблице стилей и сработает

Comment: @MaximLensky как я пропишу относительные пути в css, если я стараюсь уйти от этого, то есть, я в поисках "иного" решения (если таковое вообще, возможно).
Именно поэтому пути идут в style к самому элементу

Comment: ну наверно html должен быть максимально чистый а стилизование проводить в таблице

Comment: @MaximLensky я не против вашего подхода, и в 97% случаев я его придерживаюсь. Сейчас же вопрос о другом, возможно, я не вижу очевидного варианта решения моей проблемы, и Вы можете подсказать?

Кроме того, указывать некоторые стили в самом файле - не серьёзное "нарушение", это можно практиковать в некоторых случаях, особенно в случаях - когда этими "элементами" нужно "управлять".

Comment: https://codepen.io/yamich/pen/vYEYNGz вот немного наркомании

Comment: @Yamich спасибо, я ищу варианты решения без абсолютного позиционирования)

Comment: если бы боитесь что изображения не поместиться тогда можете увеличить ширину позиционированного блока.
В таком случае используйте свг) и не позиционируйте))
А если вам нужен отступ текста вы его можете задать и отступом)